# Java Generics for class objects implementing a specific interface

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define 
**HashMap< ? , String>**
 where **?** is a class object from some implementation of a given interface, P.

For example, for interface ISearchEngine, i want **?** to possibly be Google.class, Yahoo.class, Bing.class, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
HashMap<Class<? extends ISearchEngine>, String>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
HashMap<? extends ISearchEngine, String>
```